# How can i predict a memory error by knowing the size of the arrays being used?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, psutil

In order to process big simulation-files (>6 GB) i created a gui which leads the user through each step. Using the API of the simulation software, i created a working script for the extraction of relevant data in batches. While the program is mainly used for extracting small time intervals or only a few variables, the user may also create an output that leads to a `MemoryError`.

As i am extracting the data in batches, the result would be a `MemoryError` in one of the last-steps of the code. This is not user-friendly. I therefore want to know (with some certainty) that the output will produce a `MemoryError` and warn the user about this before executing the script. As the user can set the total-batch size to 1, i have to account for the worst case. I already though about saving the output of the API on my hard drive and later merging it.

I know that this prediction is somehow possible, because e.g. `numpy`, raises a MemoryError directly after executing the following command (with 8GB RAM):

```
>>> e = np.random.rand(2000000,1000000000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-62-b74d848e009e>", line 1, in <module>
    e = np.random.rand(2000000,1000000000)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1363, in mtrand.RandomState.rand
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 861, in mtrand.RandomState.random_sample
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 167, in mtrand.cont0_array
MemoryError
```

I could not manage to find the code where this error is raised.

**What i've tried so far:**

Using `psutil.virtual_memory()` and basic multiplication of dimensions, i compare available memory and the estimated size of the output-array:

```
import psutil

def checkForMemoryError(num_rows, num_cols):
    sizeInMemory = 1  # Factor to multiple the array dimension to convert to memory size.
    crit_size = psutil.virtual_memory().available  # Get available ram and provide threshold
    trajOutSize = num_cols * num_rows  # Size of trajOut in last interation
    if trajOutSize * sizeInMemory > crit_size:
        raise MemoryError
```

I think this approach is somewhat bad, as the psutil.virtual_memory() return values that don't match the sys.getsizeof() output:

```
In[59]: e = np.random.rand(2000,1000000)
In[60]: sys.getsizeof(e)
Out[60]: 16000000112
In[61]: psutil.virtual_memory().total
Out[61]: 8278392832
```

In this example, the size of the np.array is double the size of the total available memory. I think this is because of the way numpy stores and processes data. 
If it is of interest/help for you, the output of the API is a simple `list`. I later convert this 2D-list to a dataframe in order to save it as .hdf or .csv.

Comment: Note, `list` objects will normally be **much much** larger than a similarly sized numeric `numpy.ndarray` object. Unless that `ndarray` is of `dtype=object`.

Comment: Well, if your output is a list predicting the size of an array isn't a very accurate way to predict memory errors.  You might try changing your program to output an array, and pre-allocating the output array once the user has selected what will be processed.  That will raise the error early on.

Comment: As the api is commercial, i can not alter the output to be an array. However i directly convert it to a numpy array and delete the `list` object. Pre-allocation would be a solution, however if the array size is close raising a MemoryError, numpy wont raise the MemoryError and instead create the object. This takes some time and make the whole gui lag. This is why i seek some solution like numpy seems to have it, predicting the MemoryError before it occurs.